# Best way to fix/modify a 3rd party jar without the source code

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

My application makes use of a third party jar that I want to improve and that has bugs in it. I can see from using a decompiler where the bugs are and can easily fix them. I am unable to extend the class and overwrite the problem methods as they are private and final, and make use of private and final fields.

At the moment, I solve this using a decompiler (which isn't perfect) to re-create the class in a project with the same class name, package etc. My gradle build script then extracts the contents of the original jar to `$buildir/main/java` so that when gradle compiles my version of the class, it overwrites the broken one, resulting in a new jar that is bug free.

I think this method is dirty and unmaintainable as if a new version comes out, merging changes could be difficult. Also, Eclipse and IntelliJ won't build the project when both projects are in my workspace with a `compile project` dependency, even though it builds on the command line, as the IDE is unable to see the source for all the extracted jar, but only the class I redefine to fix.

What is the best way to cleanly solve this problem?

Comment: This depends on what sort of "third-party" jar it is. Open-source? Closed-source? Vendor out of business?

Comment: It is closed source with a long time between updates, say, every 12 months. It must be used. There is no alternative.

Comment: Either use reflection, or just decompile the whole jar, create a separate project for it, put it into VCS and compile it into a new jar/dependency. When the new version comes, do a diff.

Comment: That's good in theory but the decomile process is not reliable. Not everything decompiles and it is not guaranteed to decompile the same way between versions. I will look into reflection though.